# iOS Cache Library not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching

I built a VERY simple cache class for my iOS app yet while it seems to save the data given to it it's never able to retrieve it. My Cache system should work by creating a CachedObject that stores the Object to cache, the key, and an expiration date. It then should archive that object and save to a file named key.cache.

Cache.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Cache : NSObject

    +(void)setValue:(NSObject<NSCoding> *)value forKey:(NSString *)key expires:(NSDate *)expire;

    +(NSObject<NSCoding> *)getValueFromKey:(NSString *)key;

    @end
```

Cache.m

```
    #import "Cache.h"
    #import "CachedObject.h"
    #define CACHE_LOCATION @"Library/test"

    @implementation Cache

    +(void)setValue:(NSObject<NSCoding> *)value forKey:(NSString *)key expires:(NSDate *)expire
    {
        if ((value == nil) || (key == nil))
        {
            return;
        }
        CachedObject *obj = [[CachedObject alloc] initWithObject:value expires:expire forKey:key];
        NSError *error;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:CACHE_LOCATION withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error])
        {
            [error release];
            return;
        }
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.cache", key];
        NSString *fileFullPath = [CACHE_LOCATION stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:obj toFile:fileFullPath];
        [fileName release];
        [obj release];
    }

    +(NSObject<NSCoding> *)getValueFromKey:(NSString *)key
    {
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.cache", key];
        NSString *fileFullPath = [CACHE_LOCATION stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        CachedObject *obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileFullPath];
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        if ((obj != nil) && (obj.expires != nil) && ([obj.expires compare:today] != NSOrderedAscending))
        {
            obj = nil;
        }
        [fileName release];
        if (obj != nil)
        {
            obj = [obj autorelease];
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @end
```

CachedObject.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface CachedObject : NSObject<NSCoding>
    {
        NSObject<NSCoding> *_object;
        NSDate       *_expires;
        NSString     *_key;
    }

    @property (readonly) NSObject<NSCoding> *object;
    @property (readonly) NSDate       *expires;
    @property (readonly) NSString     *key;

    -(id)initWithObject:(NSObject<NSCoding> *)aObject expires:(NSDate *)aExpires forKey:(NSString *)aKey;

    @end
```

CachedObject.m

```
    #import "CachedObject.h"
    #define EXPIRE_KEY @"expires"
    #define KEY_KEY @"key"

    @implementation CachedObject

    @synthesize object = _object;
    @synthesize expires = _expires;
    @synthesize key = _key;

    -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    {
        [_object encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_expires forKey:EXPIRE_KEY];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_key forKey:KEY_KEY];
    }

    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            _object = [_object initWithCoder:aDecoder];
            if (self.object == nil)
            {
                return nil;
            }
            _expires = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:EXPIRE_KEY] retain];
            _key = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_KEY] retain];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(id)initWithObject:(NSObject<NSCoding> *)aObject expires:(NSDate *)aExpires forKey:(NSString *)aKey
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            _object = aObject;
            _expires = aExpires;
            _key = aKey;
        }
        return self;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Can you try removing your date check in getValueFromKey: ? it could be that there is some problematic logic there. - EDIT: That is the problem, take a look at my answer.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that makes use of this Cache? Are you not getting any values out of the cache, or are just pieces of the CacheObject missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the issue might be the way you're serializing your `_object` instance variable inside `CachedObject.m` (Perhaps any NSCoding experts can prove me wrong?)

I think instead of:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    {
        [_object encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_expires forKey:EXPIRE_KEY];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_key forKey:KEY_KEY];
    }
```

You want to use:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    {
        [aCoder encodeObject:_object forKey:OBJECT_KEY];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_expires forKey:EXPIRE_KEY];
        [aCoder encodeObject:_key forKey:KEY_KEY];
    }
```

Since you want to treat `_object` as an instance variable, similar to your `_expires` and `_key` objects.

**Side Note:** When autoreleasing objects, you don't need to do this:

```
if (obj != nil)
{
    obj = [obj autorelease];
}
return obj;
```

You can just do:

```
return [obj autorelease];
```

Comment: I did the nil check at the end because I wasn't sure if I should autorelease nil
(also made me realize I was returning the wrong object, meant to return obj.object)

Comment: Ah, this is a fundamental difference between Objective-C and some other languages. **Method calls to `nil` are no-ops.** They will not throw exceptions, and calling methods on `nil` that have defined return values will always return `0`, `false`, `nil`, etc. It's common to check for `nil` if you need to report an error or perform some other branch of execution, but otherwise you can save a few lines of code. :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [NSComparator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) docs,

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

You need to replace `NSOrderedAscending` with `NSOrderedDescending` in your `-getValueForKey:` method.

Comment: Upvote. It can take some head scratching, but you're right. The OP is saying: "If the expiration date, compared to today, is descending (meaning the expiration date is in the future) then it has expired." **Which is incorrect.**

Comment: @craig and thats why I always use > 0 or < 0, because using names like that is just confusing.

Comment: Thanks for that point, not marking it as the answer since it wasn't the problem I was having during testing (was passing nil for the expiration) thanks! (would upvote but can't yet)

Comment: @SamuelEnglard But to be fair, Richard's answer was much closer than mine. And, his actually demonstrates a definite issue in your code. :) My answer is mostly speculative.

Comment: @craig you do bring a good point, wish I could mark both as answers! I'll leave as is for same reason as above though. (And don't sell your answer short, even if I had done his fix that would still have been a problem)